# Finding duplicate consecutive strings in vim using vim regex

Tags: html, regex, search, vim, replace

So let's say I have this in my search file

Foo
Bez, Bez
Foobar
Foo

I want to search for Bez, Bez by using a regex.

This is what I have and I know it's not even remotely correct.

```
:%s/\([a-zA-Z]\),\([a-zA-Z])/\1,\1,\1/g
```

So basically what I want to do is make "Bez, Bez" into "Bez, Bez, Bez"

Really, I'm stumped on how to find 2 consecutive equivalent strings.

Comment: I do not think you can test equality with regex in vim like this - you need to use a higher level tool, maybe gawk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about:

```
%s/\(\w\+\), \1/\1, \1, \1/g
```

it captures the expression between the parenthesis even before ending the expression whole match, pretty neat huh?.

Comment: the first match, meaning what's in the parenthesis is saved in `\1` so when you get in the same sentence this `\1` to match you can be sure it's the same expression

Comment: Got ya - my mistake - upvoting

Comment: Learned something today - did not know you could do that - vim never ceases to amaze me even using it for near on 15 years

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!
This unfortunately won't work on a string such as
"A kite, a kite"
I could do %s/\(\w\s\w\+\), \1/\1, \1, \1/g.
Unfortunately that's not working either

Comment: Ah, the reason why it didn't work is because I had my case sensitivity turned on!  I had to make sure it was turned off and everything was good to go.

Comment: Great! happy to help, I was like damn why it doesn't work for him! hah

Answer (score 1):

You use capturing groups such as:

```
(\w+)\W+\1
```

but I don't recall the vim equivalent for such regex expression.

I tested using [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) and the input you gave

[image: Test Equality in RegexPal]

**Edit**

Found [Back References in Vim](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences)

Comment: @AdrianCornish Please explain

Comment: The OP's question title is `Finding duplicate consecutive strings in vim using vim regex` where do you test if the match is the same?

Comment: @AdrianCornish Tested in regexpal using a capturing group

Comment: This could be the same mistake I made with other answer - removing the -1 because now I am unsure

Comment: @AdrianCornish is exactly the same idea as Hassek

Comment: @AdrianCornish by the way thanks for adding comment for the downvote (otherwise I wouldn't know the reason) :D

Comment: Probably - I am just being biased because you did not use vim :-) to answer the question (ps I hate drive by downvoters)

Comment: I have to admit I didn't understand it either because it was not vim syntax :p

Comment: @Hassek I was using old-fashioned REGEX that way it can be translated to your scripting language of preference :P I don't come from a vim background.